# Getting problem in updating app on device Amlogic EM95X - Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, app-update

I am getting problem in updating app on my device. I am using android studio 3.6.3. When I first install app on device, it got installed successfully, but when I try to update the same build again, I am getting this error:

`Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'shell_responsive'`.

I have also tried updating the build on my device using adb, but every time I do it, I am getting different error messages e.g

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'closed'
```

I am also getting these error sometimes while updating build through adb: `INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY and BUILD_ALREADY_EXISTS`